# Perspective transformation using R and magick

Tags: r, image-processing, imagemagick, camera-distortion

I am trying prescriptive transformation with `R` `magick` package.

I want to deskew and correct the prespective in the following image.

[image]

I am not able to get the desired result. What am I doing wrong here ?

```
library(magick)

imgfile <- "test_skew.jpg"
img <- magick::image_read(imgfile)

# input coordinates
inp <- list(x = c(29.5740973594396, -6.62134003951859, 322.64038081552, 
                  307.461649003054), 
            y = c(-5.74456619364109, 515.002694449434, 
                  490.483204598527, -2.24178192922578))


plot(img)
polygon(inp$x, inp$y, border = "red")

text(inp$x[1], inp$y[1], label = "1", col = 'red')
text(inp$x[2], inp$y[2], label = "2", col = 'red')
text(inp$x[3], inp$y[3], label = "3", col = 'red')
text(inp$x[4], inp$y[4], label = "4", col = 'red')


# output coordinates
outp <- list(y = c(0, 520, 520, 0),
             x = c(0, 0, 334, 334))

polygon(outp$x, outp$y, border = "blue")

text(outp$x[1]+10, outp$y[1]+10, label = "1", col = 'blue')
text(outp$x[2]+10, outp$y[2]-10, label = "2", col = 'blue')
text(outp$x[3]-10, outp$y[3]-10, label = "3", col = 'blue')
text(outp$x[4]-10, outp$y[4]+10, label = "4", col = 'blue')
```

I want to make the black border a perfect rectangle by distorting the input coordinates (red) to the output coordinates (blue).

[image]

```
# inx1,iny1 outx1,outy1 .... inx4,iny4 outx4,outy4
distc <- c(inp$x[1], inp$y[1], outp$x[1], outp$y[1],
           inp$x[2], inp$y[2], outp$x[2], outp$y[2],
           inp$x[3], inp$y[3], outp$x[3], outp$y[3],
           inp$x[4], inp$y[4], outp$x[4], outp$y[4])

magick::image_distort(img, 
                      "perspective", distc)
```

[image]

The desired result is as follows.

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what the second and third images are please? And what the actual problem is? Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I want to make the black border a perfect rectangle by distorting the input coordinates (red) to the output coordinates (blue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't read `R` so a lot of your code is lost on me, however, I can tell you the command-line parameters you would need to use to make **ImageMagick** do what you want. So hopefully you can adapt that to solve your question.

The parameters to `-distort perspective` are 4 pairs of points:

```
[x,y] coords of point 1, [x,y] coords where it must be mapped to
[x,y] coords of point 2, [x,y] coords where it must be mapped to
[x,y] coords of point 3, [x,y] coords where it must be mapped to 
[x,y] coords of point 4, [x,y] coords where it must be mapped to
```

So for your specific image:

```
magick FgvGK.png -distort perspective "271,520 238,524 241,91 238,78 507,111 524,78 495,518 524,524" true.jpg
```

which yields:

[image]

and hopefully you can see the black frame is now rectangular.

Comment: what if you do not know the exact coordinates of the "corrected coordinates"? also how does this compare to deskew?

Comment: @ina The *"deskew"* operation can only perform ***rotation***, nothing else. So if you deskew a page of 8.5x11  hand-written text, it will still be 8.5x11 afterwards,  but just rotated. The operation in this answer though can move the four corners (or any other control points you choose) relative to each other, so the shape can change completely. If you don't know the points, you can't really use it - though I'm not sure what you are getting at really. HTH.

Comment: well, for example when you take a photo of a piece of paper, the length and width remain invariant even though the photo will distort it so that it is not perfectly orthogonal... what if you do not know the length and width of the paper a priori? how do you un-distort it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77776955/imagemagick-un-skewing-photo-of-a-photo