# imagemagick adjust perspective of image based on rectangle

Tags: imagemagick

How do you adjust the perspective of an image to be based on a recognized bounding rectangle in the image. For example, recognize any of the rectangles in the image below and adjust the angle so it is perfectly normal to the card (and also crop it)

[image]

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75776370/2836621