# imagemagick un-skewing photo of a 2D Object

Tags: imagemagick

Suppose you have a photo of a pice of paper (or otherwise approx 2D object), i.e., distortion is presented both on the plane of the 2D object (possibly bent) and the camera angle.

The 2D object is rectangular. However, the length and width are unknown a priori.

How do you automate correcting the de-skewing?

Note, I don't think `deskew` applies since that seems to be flatbed scanners.

Input Examples:

[image: Image from Gyazo]

[image: Image from Gyazo]

Comment: Those photos do not seem to need any deskewing. They are rectangular already.  What exactly do they need?  If they are not perfectly rectangular, you can find the 4 corners and then use a perspective warp to correct it to perfectly rectangular.  Removing wrinkles is not easy and there is no unique imagemagick function for that.  See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#perspective

Comment: the shown in the photo are not rectangular - it's not about de-wrinkling per se, but about having the paper perfectly map to an orthogonal photo angle

Comment: Find the four corners of the paper in an image, compute the 4 desired corners of a rectangle of the same size, then use +distort perspective to rectify the image to a perfect rectangle.  See the link above